# Can I put geom text on the graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to put `**` on the graph. 
But it have a problem with the 'big port' column (see image below). 
I wonder why it's working well with 'small port' column but not with 'big port' column.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
plot1
     Station      mean       sd   n        se
1  Big port  2.0194721 6.366281 206 0.4435598
2 Small port 0.6559439 1.099545 105 0.1073046

label.df1<-data.frame(Station=c(" Big port","Small port"),mean = c(2.6,1))
p<-ggplot(plot1,aes(x=Station,y=mean))
p1<-p+geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge")+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se),position = "dodge", width=0.2)
p2+geom_text(data=label.df1,label="**")
```

Comment: There's a typo: you have `" Big port"`, not `"Big port"`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue likely lies in how you have structured your data. I cant recreate your data from your example. I, therefore, create some new data similar to that I think you have from reading your example.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create Data

df <- data.frame(
  port = c(rep("Big", 10), rep("Small", 10)),
  value = c(rnorm(n = 10, mean = 50, sd = 25), rnorm(n = 10, mean = 25, sd = 10 ))) %>% 
  group_by(port) %>% 
  summarise(
    mean = mean(value),
    sd = sd(value),
    n = n(),
    se = sd/sqrt(n)
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   port   mean    sd     n    se
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Big    46.3 25.0     10  7.90
#> 2 Small  21.6  8.60    10  2.72

# Create plot

ggplot(df, aes(x=port, y=mean))+
  geom_col()+           # Using geom_col instead of geom_bar
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), width = 0.2)+
  geom_text(aes(
    label=c("*", "**"), # The labels that you want 
    y = mean+se+5))   # Notice the y position is using the mean+se+ an extra value, this ensures that the text goes above the errorbar
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>